# Select random row per column value from Hive table

Tags: hive, subquery, hiveql

I am trying to retrieve a random row for each distinct value for column `hash`. I also need the dt column.

So far I arrived at this not-working query:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t PARTITION(dt)
    SELECT hash, dt FROM (
        SELECT hash, RAND() as r, dt FROM t1
            UNION
        SELECT hash, RAND() as r, dt FROM t2
    ) result
    WHERE r IN (SELECT MAX(r) FROM result WHERE hash=result.hash);
```

The query fails with error `Table not found 'result'` due to using it in the FROM clause `FROM result`.

How can I fix this query or what other approach to use here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to get the row with max value per hash ordered by r.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE t PARTITION(dt)
    SELECT hash,dt
    FROM (SELECT hash, dt, row_number() over(partition by hash order by r desc) as rnum 
          FROM (SELECT hash, RAND() as r, dt FROM t1
                UNION ALL
                SELECT hash, RAND() as r, dt FROM t2
               ) result
         ) t
    WHERE rnum=1
```